# What does "v5" at the end of a package name mean?

Tags: package-management

I've stumbled upon packages with names ending in `v5` such as

```
libmysql++3v5
libsigc++-2.0-0v5
libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
libxml++2.6-2v5
```

.
What does the `v5` at the end mean? I could not find anything with `v4` at the end or similar. (except when the `v` was a part of the name proper)

For example, see [this listing](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libgtkmm-3.0-1v5).